# Return array of bitstrings after generating instead of just printing

Tags: java, arrays, bitstring

This is the code from geeksforgeeks which generates and print bitstrings of n bits but I want to know instead of printing the array, how can I store the values of the array or return it so  I can use the values in the main method.

```
import java.util.*; 

class GFG 
{ 

// Function to print the output 
static void printTheArray(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    { 
        System.out.print(arr[i]+" "); 
    } 
    System.out.println(); 
} 

// Function to generate all binary strings 
static void generateAllBinaryStrings(int n, 
                            int arr[], int i) 
{ 
    if (i == n) 
    { 
        printTheArray(arr, n); 
        return; 
    } 

    // First assign "0" at ith position 
    // and try for all other permutations 
    // for remaining positions 
    arr[i] = 0; 
    generateAllBinaryStrings(n, arr, i + 1); 

    // And then assign "1" at ith position 
    // and try for all other permutations 
    // for remaining positions 
    arr[i] = 1; 
    generateAllBinaryStrings(n, arr, i + 1); 
} 

// Driver Code 
public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
    int n = 4; 

    int[] arr = new int[n]; 

    // Print all binary strings 
    generateAllBinaryStrings(n, arr, 0); 
} 
} 

// This code is contributed by 
// Surendra_Gangwar
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Change the return type
2. Add a return statement

Like this:

```
// Function to generate all binary strings 
static int[] generateAllBinaryStrings(int n, 
//     ^^^^^ change return type
                            int arr[], int i) 
{ 
    if (i == n) 
    { 
        printTheArray(arr, n); 
        return; 
    } 

    // First assign "0" at ith position 
    // and try for all other permutations 
    // for remaining positions 
    arr[i] = 0; 
    generateAllBinaryStrings(n, arr, i + 1); 

    // And then assign "1" at ith position 
    // and try for all other permutations 
    // for remaining positions 
    arr[i] = 1; 
    generateAllBinaryStrings(n, arr, i + 1); 

    return arr;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^ add return statement
}
```

Comment: I did that but it only returns 1

Comment: Well I think you should make an attempt at making changes to the code.  We're not a code writing service after all.